# dynamic <img> refresh with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic, refresh

I'm trying to get an user input image to refresh say every two seconds. The javascript gets user input for an URL and the javscript adds it to the page. Then the images loaded need to refresh every 2 seconds but i can't get it to refresh properly without refreshing the whole page or reloading from the cache:

```
function getImg(){

var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.className="imageWrapper";
var img=document.createElement('img');
img.src=url;
div.appendChild(img);
document.getElementById('images').appendChild(div);
return false;
}

setInterval(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
       var time = (new Date()).getTime();
       $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + time );
    });
}, 2000);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Don't you need AJAX for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

When you need to force reload the resource, you have to add a dymmy queryString at the end of your url:

```
<img id="img1" src="myimg.png?dummy=23423423423">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#img1').attr('src','myimg.png?dummy=23423423423');
```

and change the dummy value for each refresh

Answer (score 0):

Your premise seems good, not sure why it isn't working. Why mixing and matching jQuery with non-jquery? This is a modification of your code, but it is a working example. You should be able to adapt it for your purpose.

http://jsfiddle.net/zr692/1/

You can create elements via jQuery easily. See the modified `getImg` function I created. Ia also switched from `attr` to `prop` which is the recommended means of accessing the `src` attribute in jQuery 1.7+.

```
function getImg() {
    var url = 'http://placehold.it/300x300/123456';
    var $div = $('<div />');
    var $img = $('<img />', { src: url });
    $div.append($img);
    $('body').append($div);
}

getImg();

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        var oldurl = $(this).prop('src');
        var newurl = oldurl.substring(0, oldurl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + time.toString().substr(7, 6);
        $('#output').html(newurl);
        $(this).prop('src', newurl);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a container as:

```
<div id="container"><img src=""../> </div>
```

then simply update the content of the container as:

```
$('#container').html('<img src="newSource"../>');
```